# Font ygoth at 720 not found

Tags: fonts, pdftex, miktex

This is what happens when i try compile on miktex via pdflatex command my .tex file

I have MikTex 2.9.

This problem doesn't happen with it on another computer with MiKTex 2.9

Both miktex's are just installed.

METAFONT failed for some reason

Sorry, but makepk did not succeed.

!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file ygoth): Font ygoth at 720 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Could you, please, tell what is wrong?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Ok, I'll  cut out the most parts of it, so it would contain the problem part, i'll need a little time

Answer (score 2):

ygoth is a type1 (pfb) font but your miktex seems not to find it. Normally this means that the map file has not been activated correctly. Try if it works if you  run on the command line

```
updmap
```

You can also load the map-file manually in your document:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\pdfmapfile{=gothict1.map}
\begin{document}
\font\test=ygoth
\test abc 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you, please, help me with command line part. How do I use updmap? Do i type it like >>>updmap ygoth?

Comment: Simply type `updmap`.

Comment: Seems that nothing happened and I still have the problem

Comment: I'll try the other thing you suggested
upd. It helped! MiKTeX downloaded smth and no more error occured. Thank you